# Show error message in veiw correspoing to action method in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I need to show exception that occurred in on the same view in mvc on click of sumit button of view..

i have a exception filter in App_Start that register in application start event
but when exception occurred it show the same error page always

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1068/aspnet-mvc-exception-handling

might this will solve your query